# How to find the smallest gradient along the contour lines?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, gradient, contour

There are six charges, two negative (yellow), and four positive (blue) confined to a plane as shown below.

I plotted the equal potential lines. Now, I want to draw several lines that follow the smallest potential gradient (black lines). These lines have the properties such that they do not touch any positive charges, but always end at negative charges.

I did this in MATLAB, and I found that for any point on the black lines, if I calculate the potential distribution on a line segment that is perpendicular to the tangent at that point, the smallest potential is always achieved at that point.

Although it is possible to found such points by hand when there are not many charges, and I can then connect them to make the black curves. I am wondering if there is any way to automate this process? When dealing with different orientations, how do I choose the 'right area' to find the smallest potential points? If I look at the whole domain, the smallest potential points are usually located faraway from the charges.

Thank you so much for your time looking at this problem. Please comment below if you have any thoughts.

Cheers,
Mike

Here are my plots:

1. equal potential lines with field line:

   [image: MATLAB plot 1]
2. equal potential lines with boundaries:

[image: MATLAB plot 2]

Here is the codes.

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(0:.1:20, 0:.1:20);
x = [ 5 15 10 7 9 2];
y = [ 10 10 17 4 13 18];
q = [ 2 1 -2 2 -3 2];

U = zeros(201, 201, 2);
UU = zeros(201, 201);

for i = 1:6
    r = sqrt((X-x(i)).^2 + (Y-y(i)).^2 + 0.01);   % to avoid NaN
    U(:,:,i) = q(i)./r;
    UU = UU + U(:,:,i);
end

[dx, dy] = gradient(-UU); 
%quiver(X, Y, dx, dy,2 );


% define the starting point of stremlines (electric field lines)
% originating from positive charges

th = linspace(0,360,19)*pi/180;
x0 = 0.1 * cos(th); 
y0 = 0.1 * sin(th); 

x1 = 1 * cos(th);
y1 = 1 * sin(th);

hold on 

for i = 1:6
    if q(i) > 0 
    streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, x0 + x(i), y0 + y(i));
    end       
end

% plot the boundaries, starting points picked by trial and error

streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 13.20, 6.73)
streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 13.19, 6.75)

streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 1.85, 13.36)
streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 1.84, 13.36)

streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 5.58, 7.05)
streamline(X, Y, dx, dy, 5.58, 7.04)

hold off
```

Comment: Aren't you actually finding curves of highest gradient of the potential? The curves of smallest gradient are the contour lines themselves. Or am I misunderstanding something about the problem?

Comment: I guess, you are looking for stream lines, which can be calculated with a differential equation.

Comment: Are you sure your picture is right?  Your field lines look fine.  Steepest gradient goes between unlike charges, zero gradient along equipotential lines (as Ted said).  The lines you have drawn don't appear to have any common relation to the potential/field (that "branch point" looks particularly suspicious!)

Comment: @anon0909 Yes you are right. The 'boundary' between the top left and middle left positive charges only goes to the lower negative charge. I have updated the plot above.

Comment: @NicoSchertler   Actually, I am looking for streamlines. I have updated my plots in the original question. The way I plotted these 'boundaries' is to find a point somewhere between two neighboring positive charges, and use the `streamline` function to plot one streamline ending at the negative charge and another streamline ending at infinite far.

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you for your comment, I am actually looking for a smallest gradient across the contour lines (but not zero gradient). Since the distance between two contours along my 'boundaries' are largest, I think they are the smallest gradient.

Comment: The way I find these streamlines is really dumb I think. I looked at the innermost contour that contain the two positive charges which I want to divide, then I use trial and error to plot streamlines from a point somewhere near the two 'bends' of that contour. I find such a point that if I plot a streamline starting a little off, it will point to infinite far instead to the negative charge. I then plot two streamlines starting from that point and the nearby point, so that they appear to be one line. If zoom in, they are not connected. Is there anyway that I can automate this process?

Comment: @mike I like this question - but to help, I need some example data to work with.  Can you provide (a small example) of the data you're starting from?

Comment: @anon0909 Thank you for your time and help. My starting data is three 6-by-1 vectors, x, y, q. (x, y, are coordinates of the charges, and q is the strength of charges) x = [ 5 15 10 7 9 2]; y = [ 10 10 17 4 13 18]; q = [ 2 1 -2 2 -3 2]. My grid system is [X, Y] = meshgrid(0:.1:20, 0:.1:20). I used a for loop for six times, to calculate  r = sqrt((X-x(i)).^2 + (Y-y(i)).^2 + 0.01); U(:,:,i) = q(i)./r; UU = UU + U(:,:,i); After the for loop, I calculated the gradient dx and dy, which I used later to plot streamlines.

Comment: @anon0909 Here are the coordinates of the six points that I started from to plot the streamlines (13.20, 6.73); (13.19, 6.75); (1.85, 13.36); (1.84, 13.36); (5.58, 7.05); (5.58, 7.04). I have updated the codes in original question.

Comment: @mike, ok.  Put that in the question, I'll cook up an answer for you.

Comment: @anon0909 Thank you. I have put the codes above.

Comment: @mike this looks pretty good as is!  I'll take a look tomorrow, going to bed now.

Comment: @anon0909 Thank you for your time. Hope you have a good week!

Comment: @anon0909  I am stuck with this problem for a while. Can you look at if if you have a chance? Thanks

Comment: @mike Hi, I think you need to clarify your problem. Do you have a *precise* condition for these lines?  You say: `follow the smallest potential gradient (black lines)`, but 1) the smallest potential gradient would be zero (moving along equipotential) and 2) there are no black lines.  I can see these streams go through regions of two positive charge where the gradient is small, but I'm not sure you've outlined a well defined problem...  if you said what it's for, maybe the intuition would help.